# Using php Convert timestamp to Unix timestamp while fetching from Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to fetch date-with-time(timestamp) from oracle database using php.

```
<?php
    include("mydb.php");
    // run query
    $sql = "select WDAT,DATA from xet ";
    $stid=oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    // set array
    $arr = array();
    if(!$stid){
        $e=oci_error($conn);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $r=oci_execute($stid);

    if(!$r){
        $e=oci_error($stid);
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e[message],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
    }


    // look through query
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){

      $arr[] = array(strtotime($row['WDAT']) , (float)$row['DATA']);

    }

// debug:
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I'm getting the following output=>

```
[[false,15.739993],[false,13.698263],[false,13.214383],.....]
```

If i use

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){

  $arr[] = array($row['WDAT'] , (float)$row['DATA']);

}
```

then getting following output=>

```
[["25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM",15.739993],["25-FEB-15 12.33.00.000000 AM",13.698263],.....]
```

But i want the output as

```
[[1424823240,15.739993],[1424824380,13.698263],......]
```

Can't figure it out that how can i get it? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to combine both examples you suggested. You are missing strtotime on the second try when using the $row index of `'WDAT'`

The second issue is that the timestamp being returned by the db is not parsed correctly by strtotime, so it is returning false. This is do to the full timestamp including the AM/PM at the end (even though it is in 24 hour time).
We can get around this by removing it as follows:

```
<?php 
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){
    $formattedDate = str_replace( array('AM', 'PM'), '', $row['WDAT']);
    $arr[] = array(strtotime($formattedDate) , (float)$row['DATA']);
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/11tc-9was

Comment: thanks for responding. if i use strtotime then what i'm getting i already mentioned that. and in 2nd one what actually i'm getting the timestamp as  "25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM", here this is the problem. I want to convert this to unix timestamp. in oracle it's possible. but in php i have no idea. i'm new in php.

Comment: The code I put above will convert "25-FEB-15" to a timestamp

Comment: Check out the newest answer, your timestamps had an AM/PM at the end of it which wasn't parsed correctly by strtotime

Comment: thanks . but there is one small problem. if we replace am,pm with ' ' then it converts as hh24 format. 25 feb 2015 12:14:00 am become 25 feb 2015 12:14:00 in hh24 format instead of 25 feb 2015 00:14:00. output should get 1424823240 but getting 1424866440.

Comment: while fetching Wdate from database can it possible at first convert it into hh24 format and then use strtotime?

Comment: That would be my first suggestion if you had access to the database query. If you do, then convert the date to 24 hour time or some other 'normal' format

Comment: if  i change $sql= "select to_char(wdat,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') as wd, data from xet" and under while(){  $arr[] = array(($row['WD']) , (float)$row['DATA']);}  then getting the output as [["25\/02\/2015 00:14:00",15.739993],["25\/02\/2015 00:33:00",13.69],.....] and if i use strtotime then getting [[false,15.739992],......]